# Inconsistency with Authenitcaiton User-Creation in Firebase React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, android-emulator

I am trying to incorporate the Firebase JS SDK into a managed Expo React Native project. I installed Firebase through npm i firebase and I am using the latest version.

The problem is that whenever I start the expo app, through an Android emulator, I, when passing the input from formik into createUserWithEmailAndPassword first get the auth/network-request-failed error message, but after clicking the signup button several times, more than 10, it somehow works. The user is then added to the Firebase console. After this it works flawlessly, and I can create multiple accounts without fail. However, should I restart the app, then I would have to repeat the steps above.

I have divided the main firebase function to a separate file, and imported it.

The exported file:

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword } from 'firebase/auth'; 
import firebaseConfig from './app/config/Firebase/firebaseConfig';

let myApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(myApp);

export function signupEmail(email, password) {
    console.log(email, password);
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)                    
    .then((userCredential) => {
    const user = userCredential.user;
    console.log('Signed in');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
    });
}
```

The main parts of the sign-up file:

```
function handleSignup(values) {
    signupEmail(values.email, values.password);
}

<SubmitButton
    style={styles.signupButton}
    title='SignUp'
    onPress={handleSubmit}
/>

onSubmit={(values) => [handleSignup(values)]}
```

After pressing Signup I get the email and password printed out, as in the signupEmail function. I get the email and password message whether or not it is successful in the end, which I assume implies the problem doesn't lie with formik, since the data is correctly passed to the signupEmail function. Though, from here it often stands idle, sometimes for more than 10s before the network error message comes up. When it is successful, I think, is always instant.

I also have a print-out auth.currentUser button, which returns null whilst the process is loading, and if successful logs out the expected object. Though, sometimes it logs out the object to an account whose email that I didn't add during the current session. I did also add a Sign Out function which turns the auth.currentUser object into null.

I don't know where to go from here, and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to be related to the Android emulator, Expo Go on my phone worked without issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).